# Docker build: command output to host file system

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create an image with installed SQL server with docker for windows.

```
docker build -t my-sqlserver .
```

Unfortunately downloaded installation package exits with some arcane error. I'm hoping to get more info if I redirect output to a file. But file isn't being created on my host folder.
From docs I thought that ADD . / will mount current dir on host to root folder inside image.
Next line copies install package downloaded from microsoft site.
Than we run it with silent install parameters and redirecting output to sqlinstall.log file.
But it's not created! How should I do this please?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
EXPOSE 1433
ADD . /
COPY SQL2019-SSEI-Dev.exe /
RUN SQL2019-SSEI-Dev.exe /Q /V /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION="install" /PID="AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE" /FEATURES=SQL,Tools > /sqlinstall.log
```

BTW, initially problem is that image microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer doesn't work either and throws errors upon start.

Comment: If you want to debug installation: remove the last line, then run interactive `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 cmd`. when the shell is open try to run your install command.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I get error during docker build - not docker run.

Comment: Does this mean that if you omit the last line,  build the image and run, then open the cmd and launch the command to install SQL it runs fine?

Comment: Nickolodeon, what Max has suggested will probably still help you. I think what they're suggesting that you use one of the intermediate containers in the build process to open a shell and try to figure out what the next line in the Dockerfile ought to be to fix your bug. https://www.joyfulbikeshedding.com/blog/2019-08-27-debugging-docker-builds.html is a good guide if you don't know what we're talking about. :)

Comment: Thanks Max and SaraSinback ! Indeed I can just create partial image and run it with command line which is awesome!